# Count the number of successively fulfilled conditions in Spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

Please help me to count the number of successively fulfilled conditions.

I have a table with different metrics and their values per month. I also have a target value and condition per each metric:

```
Metric  Month   Target  Value   Expected Result
Metric1 Jan18   3.00%   2.00%   1
Metric1 Feb18   3.00%   2.50%   2
Metric1 Mar18   3.00%   2.30%   3
Metric1 Apr18   3.00%   3.50%   0
Metric1 May18   3.00%   3.40%   0
Metric1 Jun18   3.00%   2.00%   1
Metric2 Jan18   90.00%  95.00%  1
Metric2 Feb18   90.00%  93.00%  2
Metric2 Mar18   90.00%  80.00%  0
Metric2 Apr18   90.00%  91.00%  1
Metric2 May18   90.00%  92.00%  2
Metric2 Jun18   90.00%  93.00%  3
```

I need to count the number of months the condition is continuously met.
E.G. Metric 1 should be less than 3%, and metric 2 should be more than 90%. Please see the expected result in the table.

Comment: Please choose one app.  They are not the same and formulas for one may or may not work in the other.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,
 IF(((A2:A="metric1")*(D2:D<=C2:C))+
    ((A2:A="metric2")*(D2:D>=C2:C)), 1, 0)))
```

[image]

and then drag down:

```
=IFERROR(IF(F2=0, 0, IF(A2=A1, F2+G1, 1)), F2)
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks! And how to make it also work if the data is not in order?